# Proper usage for the word "obverse"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, vocabulary, word-usage

I believe "obverse" has several meanings, with one being "the flip side of something (coin)."

I'm trying to cleverly contrast opposite approaches of a person's management duties.

"From a wide angle view, she oversees the organization's operations and business developments, while obversely attending to the concurrent needs of individual clients."

Is this the right usage of the word "obversely" to contrast "wide" with "individual?"  Is there one word that means both obverse and concurrent?  What I'm trying to say is "while on the flip side at the same time."

Is there more eloquent way to make the statement.  I really want to juxtapose the manager's effectiveness in her broad (wide) management duties against the individual  (narrow) needs of clients.

Thanks to all who respond!

Comment: Perhaps *contrapuntally*?

Answer (score 1):

I certainly wouldn't use 'obverse' which effectively means 'opposite'. And when you think about it, the narrowly focused aspects of any job do not really stand in antithesis to its wider preoccupations, do they?

I think I would say something like:

'Broadly she oversees the organisation's operations and business developments, whilst also attending to the day-to-day needs of individual clients.'

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are intentionally trying to obfuscate your language, I would go for something like

> From a wide angle view, she oversees the organization's operations and business developments, while *also* attending to the concurrent needs of individual clients.

Personally, I would not use *from a wide angle view* it sounds strange and cumbersome. Also not clear on your use of *concurrent*. Concurrent to *what*? To her other duties? Is it the customer's needs that are concurrent? The many needs to each other? The many customer's needs to other customers?

Comment: I don't think he's trying to obfuscate but definitely convey sophistication which is typical of business marketing speak. I too agree that *concurrent* may be the wrong word choice. Perhaps OP means *current*.

Comment: @AlexW I guessed as much but was attempting to subtly imply that there is a very real difference between obfuscated and needlessly pretentious wording and sophistication.